# Let's Encrypt Expire Bot showing different date then command line

Tags: openssl, letsencrypt

Today I got an email notification from Let's Encrypt Expire Bot that the SSL certificate for my domain will be expired on the 31, july, 2018.

but when I log in to the server, and check the certificate with this command,

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect mydomaintobeexpired.com:443 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

I got the following out,

```
notBefore=Jul  1 21:03:23 2018 GMT
notAfter=Sep 29 21:03:23 2018 GMT
```

So it looks like everything is OK?

Why does Let's Encrypt Expire Bot give me a different expiring date then what the command line shows?

Comment: It's possible that your (persumed) `cron` job updated the cert at roughly the same time that LE shot you that reminder email.

Comment: Alternatively, the server names the certificate covered may have changed the last time the certificate was renewed.  Letsencrypt only treats a cert as renewed if the new one is an exact match for the set of names on the old one.